# Angular 4/5 animating fade out when an item is removed is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, animation, settimeout, angular-animations

I am developing a web application using Angular. What I am doing now is trying to display an alert when the user click a button. The alert will slide in with animation when it is added and after 2 seconds, it will fade out automatically. I am using setTimeout to fade out the alert after 2 seconds. My code is not working.

This is my code.

```
import {
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  animate,
  transition,
  group
} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-event-list',
  templateUrl: './event-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./event-list.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('alertFade', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
        animate(350)
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        group([
          animate('2s ease', style({
            opacity: 0
          }))
        ])
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class EventListComponent implements OnInit {
  private uploadFormAlerts: any[];
  private uploadForm: FormGroup;
  private currentUploadEvent: IEvent;
  private events: IEvent[];
  private modalRef: BsModalRef;
  private files: any[];

  constructor(private eventsService: EventsService, private modalService: BsModalService, private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

   }

  onUploadFormSubmitted(uploadForm) {
    this.displayUploadFormAlert('Upload error', 'alert alert-danger')

  }

  displayUploadFormAlert(message, alertClass)
  {
    var alertItem =  [ { alert: alertClass, message: message } ];
    this.uploadFormAlerts = alertItem;
    setTimeout(this.clearUploadFormAlert(), 2000);
  }

  clearUploadFormAlert()
  {

    this.uploadFormAlerts.pop();
  }
}
```

The problem with the above code is that it is not adding any alert. But when I remove setTimeout, it is adding new alert sliding in with animation. But it does not fade out. Yes, it will not because I need `setTimeout` to remove it. When I click the button for the second time, the existing alert fades out and new alert slides in. My animation code is working.

The problem is it just does not working with setTimeout function. It is not throwing any error in the console as well. How can I properly display the fade out alert? Is there a better way or how can I fix my code?

Comment: Can you please create StackBlitz example?

Comment: Finally I am able to use clear the array in the setTimeout function. I needed to use the typescript syntax like this setTimeout(()=>{ //clear the array }, 2000). But when the alert box is removed, the animation is not working. It is not fading out. It is just removed straightaway without any animation effect. Why?

Comment: Hi Wai. I notice a grammatical error seeping into a lot of your posts, which I think you would want to know about. There are two similar words in English, "cause" and "because", and although they are related, they are used in different situations. For example, we might say _driving while tired causes accidents_, but if we are talking about a singular case, we'd say _The man had a car accident because he was tired_. The word "cause" does not work in the second case, even though in spoken informal English, the word because is sometimes shortened to "cos".